# How to manually create my function to detect outliers and to customize it

Tags: r, function, outliers

Based on the outlier detection formula, I want to create my own function  and customize it.
Here is how I do it:

```
# x the vector, th= Threshold

my_outlier<-function(
    x, th
){
  q1=quantile(x,0.25)
  q3=quantile(x,0.75)
  rg=q3-q1
  lower_bound=q1-(th*rg)
  upper_bound=q3+(th*rg)
  
  if (x<lower_bound|x>upper_bound){
    list(x)
  }else{integer(0)}
}
```

I expect to get these different results for each code::

```
my_outlier (c(1:10, 20, 100, 120), th=1.5)
[1] 20  100  120

my_outlier (c(1:10, 20, 100, 120), th=5)
    [1] 100  120

my_outlier (c(1:10), th=1.5)
    [1] integer(0)
```

Unfortunately i realize that `if statement` can return only one value.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if` directly applied over the logical expression(i.e. it expects a single TRUE/FALSE from evaluation of the expression as it is not vectorized), we can subset `x` based on the condition and then use `if/else` on the `length` of the subset.  Also, by subsetting into a object, we avoid applying the same expression twice

```
my_outlier<-function(
    x, th
){
  q1=quantile(x,0.25)
  q3=quantile(x,0.75)
  rg=q3-q1
  lower_bound=q1-(th*rg)
  upper_bound=q3+(th*rg)
  
  x1 <- x[x<lower_bound|x>upper_bound]
    if(length(x1) > 0)
    x1 else integer(0)
  
}
```

-testing

```
> my_outlier (c(1:10, 20, 100, 120), th=1.5)
[1]  20 100 120
> 
> my_outlier (c(1:10, 20, 100, 120), th=5)
[1] 100 120
> my_outlier (c(1:10), th=1.5)
integer(0)
```